# NSAssert usage in threads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, assert, nsthread, nsoperation

I'm trying to use `NSAssert` throughout my iPhone app so that if an unexpected condition occurs, the application fails-fast and crashes with a meaningful message in the crash log.

This works fine if the failing `NSAssert` is on the main thread, as it raises `NSInternalInconsistencyException` by default which is uncaught and stops execution. But I'm also doing processing in background threads, in which case the `NSAssert` just aborts the thread, but the programming keeps running.

My current solution is to catch and rethrow the exception in the main thread (in this case, `NSOperation`'s `main` method):

```
- (void)main {
    @try {
        int x = 14;
        ...
        NSAssert1(x > 20, @"x should be greater than 20, was %d", x);
        ...
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        [e performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(raise) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way? Perhaps using a custom NSAssertionHandler?

I know I could just use C's `assert` with a static annotation:

```
assert(x > 20 && "x should be greater than 20");
```

But this doesn't allow me to show what the actual failing value of `x` is.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the proposed solution won't work for me. The NSAssert is being triggered, the thread dies, but the app continues running. I'm using the Cocos2D engine. Could anybody provide a more complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `NSAssert` with a test code followed by an exception raise. This way, if the assertion failed, an exception will be thrown, catched by the `@catch` block and re-raised on the main thread.

Note: You can even define a C macro, in order to provide a compact form.

Comment: This is what NSAssert does by default -- it raises an NSInternalInconsistencyException. So you're advocating the catch/re-raise solution above?

Comment: I have re-read the documentation and NSAssert does raise an exception.  So your current solution seems right.